# css font italic shorthand not working?

Tags: css

I am trying to simply make some text be italic with font shorthand.

So far I have this;

```
font: 36px italic normal Georgia;
```

But it is not working. The font definetely can be italic as if I set `font-style: italic;` it works.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/font-shorthand/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are having a wrong short hand syntax there, it should be

```
p {
    font: italic normal 12px Georgia;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/x59DP/)

Reference :

[image]

[Image Credits](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-font-shorthand-property-cheat-sheet/)

As you see in the above image, there are some mandatory syntax for the `font` property to be declared and you need to maintain an order to make the shorthand work, since you were using `36px` at the wrong place, it was breaking out the entire property.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome image. Other resources I found were not so informative, thank you.

Comment: @user2251919 you welcome, and btw this is not my image, I've credited the website which I've picked from few months back :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
font:italic normal 36px Georgia;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhishekjain/BzSv5/)

Answer (score 0):

If you write `normal` right after `36px italic` it would be recognized or say override the italic by normal.

Use like this: `font: italic normal 36px Georgia;`

Using shorthand properties for font would be best result if you order like below

```
1. font-style
2. font-variant
3. font-weight
4. font-size/line-height
5. font-family
```

Comment: It dosen't matter, actually both are different one is style and the other one is weight

Answer (score 0):

yep c-link said it...you can't specify italics and then right after that put "normal"....

shorthand should follow this order:

```
font:{font-style font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height font-family}
```

NOTE: font-family and font-size must be specified....if not they will be put at default values...